# Proper way to insert into database when receiving a POST request

Tags: c#

My slack application currently sends buttons attached with messages. Whenever a button is clicked, it sends a post request. If the button's attached value is true, it saves a value to the database.

How the button should work is that when it's first clicked by any user, it replies with a Ok status and a message saying "Correct", anything subsequently will say "question has already been answered".

The problem i come across is that if multiple people click the button where it's attached value is set to true roughly at the same time. It'll all respons with "Correct". May I ask how should i be responding to the post request and how should i be inserting into the database `sequentially` so that only one correct is sent.

Current code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post()
{
    var payload = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "payload");
    bool value= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(payload.Value);
    using (var contexts = new TriviaBotDbContextFactory().CreateDbContext(null))
    {
        if (value)
        {
            // return if 
            var item = contexts.Questions.Include(x => x.Guesses).First(x => x.Id == question.Id);

            if (item.Guesses.Any(y => y.Correct))
                return StatusCode(200);

            // Send Message Code
            SBMClient client = new SBMClient(webHook);
            Message msg = new Message("Correct");
            client.Send(msg);

            // Save to database
            item.Guesses.Add(new Answer
            {
                Correct = true,
                User = button.user.name
            });

            await contexts.SaveChangesAsync();
        }   
    }

    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Comment: did you try to check the value in database if it's already answered before sending OK status ?

Comment: Hi @CyberProgs that's what it's doing `(item.Guesses.Any(y => y.Correct))`. Thanks for the suggestion =)

Comment: did you try to lock the record for each request for example using Pessimistic locking ?